# Combining different elements from 2 lists to create a data type?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm new to python and writing a basic poker game. The first thing I'm trying to do is print the deck of 52 cards. I've created lists for both the face values and the suits. I set up a couple loops to iterate through the faces and suits to create 52 unique cards. The problem is in printing the deck, the Ace of Spades for instance will print as 'A', 's'  which just doesn't look nice. I'd like it to just look like As. So, how can I take the value inside of one list index and sort of add it right next to another list index, so they print right next to eachother?
Or have I gone about this with the wrong construction? I was wondering if creating a data type for a playing card that has both the face value and suit.

```
faces = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
suits = ["s", "h", "d", "c"]
deck = []

for i in range (0, len(faces)):
    for j in range (0, len(suits)):
        card = (faces[i], suits[j])
        deck.append(card)
print(deck)
```

output:
  
    [('A', 's'), ('A', 'h'), ('A', 'd'), ('A', 'c'), ('2', 's'), ('2', 'h'), ('2', 'd'), ('2', 'c'), ('3', 's'), ('3', 'h'), ('3', 'd'), ('3
', 'c'), ('4', 's'), ('4', 'h'), ('4', 'd'), ('4', 'c'), ('5', 's'), ('5', 'h'), ('5', 'd'), ('5', 'c'), ('6', 's'), ('6', 'h'), ('6', '
d'), ('6', 'c'), ('7', 's'), ('7', 'h'), ('7', 'd'), ('7', 'c'), ('8', 's'), ('8', 'h'), ('8', 'd'), ('8', 'c'), ('9', 's'), ('9', 'h'),
 ('9', 'd'), ('9', 'c'), ('10', 's'), ('10', 'h'), ('10', 'd'), ('10', 'c'), ('J', 's'), ('J', 'h'), ('J', 'd'), ('J', 'c'), ('Q', 's'),
 ('Q', 'h'), ('Q', 'd'), ('Q', 'c'), ('K', 's'), ('K', 'h'), ('K', 'd'), ('K', 'c')]

Comment: For one, you can use `zip()` to have a merged copy of the two lists. Also, you can loop through the zipped list and print a formatted string, like `print(str(face) + str(suit))`.

Comment: you can also use `itertools.product` as in `deck = list(product(faces, suits))`. `itertools` is a standard [python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: I would argue there's little reason to use anything *except* `itertools.product` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can join face values and suits using something like

```
print(map(lambda h: "".join(h), deck))
```

that is using [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the two strings.
This will print and save in the form you want.

```
for i in range (0, len(faces)):
    for j in range (0, len(suits)):
        card = faces[i]+suits[j]
        deck.append(card)
print(deck)
```

Or you could save in your old format and add strings in another loop for printing as shown below. This way you store it in your data type with both attributes and while printing you are just adding them.

```
for d in deck:
  print(d[0]+d[1],end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "**,**" for "+"

```
faces = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
suits = ["s", "h", "d", "c"]
deck = []

for i in range (0, len(faces)):
    for j in range (0, len(suits)):
        card = (faces[i] + suits[j])
        deck.append(card)
print(deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the book "Fluent python" by Luciano Ramalho, you'd like his implementation of a deck of cards:

```
import collections
card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA') 
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()
    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)
    def __getitem__(self, position): 
        return self._cards[position]

 deck = FrenchDeck()
```

Now, you have a deck with all the cards info contained within it. You can randomly choose any card you want

```
 from random import choice
 print(choice(deck))
 # may print Card(rank='3', suit='hearts')
```